# Getx flutter change theme when i change theme dark and then return light mode its not loading my custom theme

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, flutter-packages

Getx flutter when i change theme from light to dark mode and then return to light mode its not returning my custom theme its load old app bar background even theme changes
[image]

```
ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    elevation: 1000,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  )
);
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.red);

Getx flutter when i change theme from light to dark mode and then return to light mode its not returning my custom theme its load old app bar background even theme changes


class _MyMaterialAppState extends State<MyMaterialApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appName,
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      translations: Languages(),
      locale: Get.deviceLocale,
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this is because of the `GetMaterialApp` widget in the `build` method. Because the `build` method is called every time the widget is updated, this means that your custom theme will be overwritten. You can do something like this:

```
class _MyMaterialAppState extends State<MyMaterialApp> {

  GetxController<ThemeData> _themeController = GetxController(lightTheme);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<GetxController<ThemeData>>(
      init: _themeController,
      builder: (_, theme) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: appName,
          theme: theme.value,
          darkTheme: darkTheme,
          translations: Languages(),
          locale: Get.deviceLocale,
          fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This code uses `GetBuilder` to listen for changes to the `_themeController` and update `theme` property.
To change the theme:

```
_themeController.updateValue(newTheme)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `GetX` Itself says that you should not depend on any higher level widget than `GetMaterialApp` in order to update it. This can trigger duplicate keys.

I have seen your code and I tried to test this on physical devide and it works perfectly fine.

Here's the code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/route_manager.dart';

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      elevation: 1000,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ));
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.red);

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyMaterialApp());
}

class MyMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMaterialApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "appName",
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      // translations: Languages(),
      locale: Get.deviceLocale,
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("data"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark);
                // Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
              },
              child: Text("Chage"),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
              },
              child: Text("Chage light"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple soln, works with the latest GetX, this approach does not require explicit state, just code injection.

start with very simple instance that contains your ThemeData

```
class Themes  {
  ThemeData darkThemeData() => ThemeData(.....
  ThemeData lightThemeData() => ThemeData( ....
```

then inject instance in your main()   `Get.put(Themes());`

then in your `GetMaterialApp(...`

```
 Themes themes = Get.find();
 GetMaterialApp(...
  theme: themes.lightThemeData(),
  darkTheme: themes.darkThemeData(),
  home:....
```

then in some related code action for example

```
  case 0:
    Get.changeTheme(Get.find<Themes>().lightThemeData());
    break;
  case 1:
    Get.changeTheme(Get.find<Themes>().darkThemeData());
```